# Подстановка кавычек

Tags: php

У меня есть такой массив (это часть запроса к БД) и для того, чтобы  добавить какое-то значение приходится оборачивать его в двойные кавычки '"test2"'. Мне нужно убрать их из массива, чтобы было так 'test2' и подставлять уже потом в условии. Как это сделать можно?

```html
$data = [
  'where' => [
      'url', '=', '"test2"',
   ],
];

if (!empty($data['where'])) {
    return $where = ' WHERE ' . implode(' ', $data['where']);
}
```

Comment: так а зачем они изначально в `'url', '=', '"test2"',` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский потому что запрос считает значение test2, как колонку.

Comment: А если не убирать, то как считает?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну как строку обычную. А без: 
Unknown column 'test2' in 'where clause'. Full query: [SELECT title, url FROM `pages` WHERE url = test2 ORDER BY id ASC

Comment: "ну как строку обычную." --- нуууу... тебе же и надо чтобы была как обычная строка....не?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так мне не нужно именно в массиве добавлять кавычки (это не удобно), а добавлять их автоматом перед вставкой  в запрос

Comment: по-другому у тебя не получится........ если бы у тебя был запрос с `IN` с перечислением значенией, то можно было....а в текущем коде у тебя выражение......в итоге тебе придётся дописывать какой-нибудь str_repace или что-то подобное. ещё больший костыль

Comment: Это еще и несекьюрно и ведет к sql-инъекциям.

Comment: @u_mulder Конечный запрос у меня такой. Разве в нем нет защиты от инъекций? $this->db->$func("SELECT ?p FROM ?n ?p ?p ?p ?p", 
            $select, $table, $join, $where, $orderBy, $groupBy);

Comment: Я не знаю что такое `$func` и как заменяются все эти `?n\?p`. Судя по `$where = ' WHERE ' . implode(' ', $data['where'])` защиты нет никакой.

Comment: @u_mulder в данному случае используется safemysql class. А $func - это getAll()

Comment: Ну хорошо что используется. И чему к примеру равен `$where`?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю лучше использовать подготовленные выражения. И тогда Ваш код может быть таким:

```
<?php
$data = [
  'where' => [
      'first_name', '=', 'NICK'
   ],
];

$query = sprintf(
    'select * from sakila.actor where `%s` %s ? ;', 
    $data['where'][0], 
    $data['where'][1]
);

echo $query;
// get DB version using PDO
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$data['where'][2]]);
$actors = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

[PHP online environment](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/c2d6b682e438e76da25f55a3a9972c93/php/php81/a6f979e6b7e3013d817f78a9a69baa07/)